# Update facebook page list in to a drop down list

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on an angular app which integrates with facebook. I have given the code below,

```
$scope.getCompanyPages = function () {            
            fb.login(function (response) {
                fb.api('/me/accounts', function (apiresponse) {
                    if (typeof apiresponse !== 'undefined' && typeof apiresponse.data !== 'undefined') {
                        $scope.facebookPages = apiresponse.data;
                        $scope.facebookPages.push({ id: "", name: 'Please select a page' });
                        $scope.selectedItem = $scope.facebookPages[2];
                        console.log($scope.facebookPages);
                    }
                });
            }, { scope: 'manage_pages' });
        };
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center">
            <a href="#" ng-click="shareToMyWall()">
                <div class="primary-task">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x">
                    </i>
                    <h2 class="heading-text fa-bold">Personal Wall</h2>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center">
            <a href="#" ng-click="getCompanyPages()">
                <div class="primary-task">
                    <i class="fa fa-building fa-3x">
                    </i>
                    <h2 class="heading-text fa-bold">Company Wall</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <select ng-if="facebookPages.length > 0" ng-change="shareToFacebookPage(selectedItem.id)" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in facebookPages track by item.id"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above method is called in hyperlink click (ng-click) event and the when the response comes back the drop down should update with data. The data does come back but it doesn't update straight away, rather I have to do another click anywhere in the page to update drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the model is updated when you do the first `ng-click`. However, AngualrJS probably does not do check so the view still shows the old data. You can force a `$digest()` check and tell AngualrJS to compare old data and new data and update it if there is any difference. You can use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), `$evalAsync`, or `$apply` to trigger `$digest()` which will update the data immediately.

For example:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.getCompanyPages = function () {...}
    //or
    $scope.facebookPages = apiresponse.data;
})
```

Edit: according to [Angular JS best coding practice](http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-best-coding-practice-every-coder-should-follow/)

> Always wrap 3rd party API call-backs in to $apply to notify AngularJS
>   regarding out of environment changes.

Comment: Thanks used the apply. 
$scope.$applyAsync(function () {
                            
                        });

Comment: @Joshua Glad to help